# How to fix inconsistent predictions right after training and after loading the saved model?

Tags: python, keras

I trained my Keras (version 2.3.1) Sequential models for a regression problem and achieved very good results. Right after training, I make predictions on the test set and then save the model *as well as* the weights in separate files.

To check for the speed of the models, I recently loaded them and made predictions on a single test input array but the results are way off, which should mean that the weights at the end of the training are different from the ones being loaded.

1. I tried making predictions using the `loaded model` as is and from the `loaded weights` too. The results for both of them are consistent. So at least, it saves the same weights in both files, however wrong they are.
2. From what I have read, this looks like a common issue with Keras. I came across this suggestion at several places - [set the global variable initializer manually](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875#issuecomment-296696536).

My problem is that this suggestion, along with a few others (like setting a fixed seed), are to be put in place *before* training. Training my models takes 4-5 days! How can I fix this without having to retrain the models?

Here is how I fit the models:

```py
hist = model.fit(
                 X_train, y_train,
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 verbose=1,
                 epochs=epochs,
                 validation_split=0.2
                )
```

Then I save the model as well as the weights:

```py
model.save("path to .h5 file")
model.save_weights("path to .hdf5 file")
```

Eventually, I am loading the model and predicting from it like so:

```py
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("path to the same .h5 file")
ypred = model.predict(input_arr)
```